# high chart data grouping is not considering all the values while zooming

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, highcharts

highstock data grouping is wrong while zooming. I am grouping data for each hour in a day.

**data grouping without zoom**

[image]

**data grouping with zoom**

[image]

as you can see from the image hour 3 and 16 not having the previous yAxis sum value anymore.

Can someone please let me know what's wrong here?

[fiddle - highstock data grouping with zoom](http://jsfiddle.net/7hymw04f/175/)

```
{
      type: 'column',
      name: 'Stock Volume',
      color: 'red',
      data: data, 
      dataGrouping: {
          forced: true,
          units: [['hour', [1]]],
          approximation: 'sum',
      }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting `series.getExtremesFromAll` to true solved my issue.

In general, only points in the visible range are grouped, points that are outside the extremes are not taken into calculations. In the docs they have mentioned only yAxis extremes, but it affects data Grouping too.

```
series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'AAPL Stock Volume',
            color: 'red',
            data: data, 
            getExtremesFromAll: true,
            dataGrouping: {
           forced: true,
          units: [['hour', [1]]],
          approximation: 'sum',
      }
        }]
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hymw04f/187/)

[github issue link](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7935)